# Bootstrap Modal Popup breaks with Partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a search view with a partial view for displaying search results.
A modal popup has to open on click of hyperlink.

My modal popup breaks in this scenario. It doesn't open as a popup anymore and looses all its styling.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The popup works if I don't use partial views.

Partial view **_SearchCustomer.cshtml**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MDMWeb.Models.CustomerModel>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<table id="tblResult" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover sortable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.Label("MDM ID")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Customer Type")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Title")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("First Name")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Surname")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Email")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Mobile")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Phone")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Private Customer")</th>
        <th>@Html.Label("Status")</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.code)
        <tr>
            <td><a data-modal="" href='@Url.Action("Edit","Customer",new { viewname = "Edit", mdmID = item.code })' title='@item.code'>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.code)</a></td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.customerType) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mobile) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phone) </td>
            <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.isPrivateCustomer) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status) </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>

 @if (Model.PageCount > 1)
 {
    <div class="box-footer clearfix">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-sm no-margin pull-right">

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("SearchCustomer", new          { page, pageSize = Model.PageSize, currentFilter = ViewBag.SearchCriteria }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divResults", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))                
    </ul>
</div>
 }
```

**Search.cshtml**

```
@model string
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
 {
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchCustomer", "Customer", new AjaxOptions
    {
      HttpMethod = "POST",
      UpdateTargetId = "divResults",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    }))
    {
     <h2>@ViewBag.PageTitle</h2>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box">
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-header with-border" id="searchCriteria">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1"><label>Created From</label></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepickerfrom" name="datepickerfrom">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <label class="pull-left">Created To</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepickerto" name="datepickerto">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <label>System</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="sourcesystem">
                                <option selected="selected">All</option>
                                <option>Salesforce</option>
                                <option>Pathway</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <label>Customer Type</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="customertype">
                                <option selected="selected">All</option>
                                <option>Individual</option>
                                <option>Organisation</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- /.box-body --> 
                <div class="box-body" id="divResults">

                </div>       
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade bs-example-modal-lg' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id='myModalContent'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @section scripts{
        @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/appjs/referenceds.js")
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var currentDate = new Date();

                $('#datepickerto').datepicker({
                    autoclose: true
                });

                $("#datepickerto").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);

                $('#datepickerfrom').datepicker({
                    autoclose: true
                });
                $("#datepickerfrom").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);            
            })
        </script>
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you getting error(s) in browser's console? I don't see you're using `Html.Partial` or `Html.RenderPartial` to render partial view in modal popup.

Comment: There is no error in browser console.

Comment: Ajax.BeginForm should close before "myModal" div in your Search.cshtml page, this is one mistake..

Comment: I have corrected it but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

u cant do that, u can do with javascript or jquery try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Movie Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">    


          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
  
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
      
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="#modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myBtn").click(function(){
                $("#myModal").modal();
                $("#modal-body").html('@Url.Content("~/{controller}/{Action}/{ID}")');
            });
         
        });

      
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Where am I supposed to add the modal popup div inside the Search View or _SearchCustomer PartialView?

Comment: ur cshtml is correct  try <div id='myModalContent'></div> set your partial view to this dom i think, $('myModalContent').html(yout partial view)

Answer (score 0):

please try this code will work for you

```
<div id='myModalContent'>
   @Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")
</div>

or

<div id='myModalContent'>
@Html.Partial("_SearchCustomer")
</div>
```

Comment: I want the modal popup to open on hyperlink click.

Comment: assign class to hyperlink    $(".hyperlinkClassName").click(function () {
       
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            return false;
    });